# Why am I getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running"?

Tags: android

I get the following error :

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
```

This is the frag:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by anameme on 10/24/2015.
 */
public class LatestJokesFrag extends Fragment{
    ListView list;

    public LatestJokesFrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        downloadImage();

    }

    public void downloadImage() {
        // OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler();

        OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler(getActivity(),
                new OkHttpHandler.MyInterface() {
                    @Override
                    public void myMethod(ArrayList result) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection Succesful",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.grid_item_layout, result);

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

        handler.execute();
        String image = null;

        try {

            image = handler.execute().get();
            Log.d("e", "hhhh handler");
            System.out.print(image);
            //if (image != null && image.length > 0){
            //  Log.isLoggable("e",image.length);
            //Log.d("e", "ddddddd entered the try");
            //      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
            //    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            //              txtBytes.setText("Total bytes downloaded: " + image.length);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("e", "rrrrrr error");

            e.printStackTrace();
//            txtBytes.setText("Hmm sorry, something went wrong!");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.latestjokesfrag, container, false);
        list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.latestjokesfrag, container, false);
    }
}
```

This is the ohttphandler

```
public class OkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Context mContext;
    private MyInterface mListener;
    public OkHttpHandler (Context context, MyInterface mListener){
        mContext = context;
        this.mListener  = mListener;
    }
    public interface MyInterface {
        public void myMethod(ArrayList result);
    }

    private final String Fetch_URL = "http://justedhak.comlu.com/get-data.php";
    ArrayList<Listitem> Listitem;
    int resulta;

    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    ListView list;
    String myJSON;
    JSONArray peoples = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
        Log.d("e", Fetch_URL);
      //   list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);

        Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
        builder.url(Fetch_URL);

        Request request = builder.build();

        String result = null;
        try {

          //  int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            //  int statusCode =200;

           // HttpEntity entity = response.body().byteStream();
         //   if (statusCode == 200) {
            Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
                resulta = 1; //"Success
                Log.d("e", "response.");
              //  return response.body().bytes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("e", "r2r2 error");
            e.printStackTrace();        }
        finally {
            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        if( resulta ==1){
            myJSON=result;
            Log.e("result",result);

            showList();
        }
        else{
            Log.e("d","zzzzzzzz");

        }
    }

    protected void showList(){
        try {
            Log.e("d","jjjjjjjjjj");

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
            Listitem = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
            for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String url = c.getString("path");
                Listitem.add(new Listitem(id,url));
                Log.e("d", "ppppp");
                System.out.println(Listitem);
            }
            if (mListener != null)
                  mListener.myMethod(Listitem);
         //   GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(mContext, R.layout.grid_item_layout, Listitem);
          //    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
     //      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       //      list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

this is full trace log:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
 at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:576)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
    10-24 10:00:14.204    1395-1416/com.justedhak.www.i D/e﹕ dddddddddd
    10-24 10:00:14.204    1395-1416/com.justedhak.www.i D/e﹕ http://justedhak.comlu.com/get-data.php
 at com.justedhak.www.i.LatestJokesFrag.downloadImage(LatestJokesFrag.java:54)
 at com.justedhak.www.i.LatestJokesFrag.onCreate(LatestJokesFrag.java:29)
 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1939)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:988)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:545)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:607)
 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:674)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
 at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2888)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2250)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1548)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6645)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call  the same handler.execute(), According to [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)  the task can be executed only once.

If you want to execute the task again you must initialize a new async task 
Please look at the method

```
downloadImage()
```

You initilize

```
OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler(getActivity()..
```

and Call

handler.execute();

Then you do it again inside the try block

```
try{
///
image =  handler.execute().get();

}
```

that causes to an error described in your post

You should initialize again a new task like below

```
  try{

      image =  new OkHttpHandler(getActivity()...).execute().get();
    }
```

Then it will work

Comment: @Moudiz edited my answer . to make my code look cleaner :)

Comment: thanks man for Problem solving :P.. however I have a new problem now , my image adapter is not working, ill post a new question can you please help me to solve it ?

Comment: I really apreciat you help , can you check please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318010/after-copying-the-imageadapter-to-fragmetn-image-is-not-displaying ?

Comment: checking  ____     :)

Comment: thank you! Helped me download multiple JSONs in the background one after the another