# after copying the imageadapter to fragment, image is not displaying

Tags: android

the Image not showing in the List adapter can you help me please?

in the log cat I am having this last message , it means I am getting the http result, however the adapter is not working

```
www.i I/System.out﹕ [com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@2c7c0f18, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1fbed71, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@3102b756, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@148873d7, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@af04c4, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1190efad]
 E/d﹕ ppppp
 I/System.out﹕ [com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@2c7c0f18, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1fbed71, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@3102b756, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@148873d7, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@af04c4, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1190efad, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@308af2e2]
 E/d﹕ ppppp
 I/System.out﹕ [com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@2c7c0f18, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1fbed71, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@3102b756, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@148873d7, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@af04c4, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1190efad, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@308af2e2, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@3df67673]
 E/d﹕ ppppp
 I/System.out﹕ [com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@2c7c0f18, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1fbed71, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@3102b756, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@148873d7, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@af04c4, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1190efad, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@308af2e2, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@3df67673, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@9f9a930]
 E/d﹕ ppppp
 I/System.out﹕ [com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@2c7c0f18, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1fbed71, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@3102b756, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@148873d7, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@af04c4, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1190efad, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@308af2e2, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@3df67673, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@9f9a930, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1bf9d9a9]
 E/d﹕ ppppp
 I/System.out﹕ [com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@2c7c0f18, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1fbed71, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@3102b756, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@148873d7, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@af04c4, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1190efad, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@308af2e2, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@3df67673, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@9f9a930, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1bf9d9a9, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@b695b2e]
 E/d﹕ ppppp
```

here is the code getting the json

```
  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
            Listitem = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
            for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String url = c.getString("path");
                Listitem.add(new Listitem(id,url));
                Log.e("d", "ppppp");
                System.out.println(Listitem);
            }
            if (mListener != null)
                  mListener.myMethod(Listitem);
```

here is code in fragment , but the adpater its not working at all

public void downloadImage() {
    // OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler();

```
//handler.execute();
String image = null;

try {
    OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler(getActivity(),
            new OkHttpHandler.MyInterface() {
                @Override
                public void myMethod(ArrayList result) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection Succesful",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.grid_item_layout, result);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

   image = handler.execute().get();
    Log.d("e", "hhhh handler");
```

this is the adapter

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Listitem> {

    private Context mcontext;
    private int layoutResourceId;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Listitem> listitem) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, listitem);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mcontext =context;

    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        Listitem item = getItem(position);
        System.out.println(item.getUrl());

        holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getId());
        Picasso.
                with(mcontext).
                load(item.getUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                .fit()
                .into(holder.imageView);

        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView imageTitle;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
```

this is the xml of the adapter

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

because its fragment , I initilaise the list here

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.latestjokesfrag, container, false);
    list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.latestjokesfrag, container, false);
}
```

i added this

```
 new OkHttpHandler.MyInterface() {
                        @Override
                        public void myMethod(ArrayList result) {
                            System.out.println("result");
```

this is result

```
www.i I/System.out﹕ result
10-24 15:22:35.000  31426-31426/com.justedhak.www.i I/System.out﹕ [com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@34435c8a, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@239ca2fb, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@2c7c0f18, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1fbed71, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@3102b756, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@148873d7, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@af04c4, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1190efad, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@308af2e2, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@3df67673, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@9f9a930, com.justedhak.www.i.Listitem@1bf9d9a9]
```

fragmetn.xml

```
public class LatestJokesFrag extends Fragment{
    ListView list;

    public LatestJokesFrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        downloadImage();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public void downloadImage() {
        // OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler();


        //handler.execute();
        String image = null;

        try {
            OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler(getActivity(),
                    new OkHttpHandler.MyInterface() {
                        @Override
                        public void myMethod(ArrayList result) {
                            System.out.println("result");

                            System.out.println(result);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection Succesful",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.grid_item_layout, result);

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    });

           image = handler.execute().get();
            Log.d("e", "hhhh handler");
           // System.out.print(image);
            //if (image != null && image.length > 0){
            //  Log.isLoggable("e",image.length);
            //Log.d("e", "ddddddd entered the try");
            //      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
            //    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            //              txtBytes.setText("Total bytes downloaded: " + image.length);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("e", "rrrrrr error");

            e.printStackTrace();
//            txtBytes.setText("Hmm sorry, something went wrong!");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.latestjokesfrag, container, false);
        list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.latestjokesfrag, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ProblemSlover I added a println and i got result value. I am stuck at this , it was working normaly in main activity , when I added it in fragment it stoped working

Comment: @ProblemSlover check my last edit please, when i added a system log i got the value of result, where do you recomand to add the breakpoints in the adapter to check the values? and i will fix the setadapter

Comment: Hey Got it. You should call method download Image in the fragment method onActivityCreated.. rather than `onCreate()` . E.g You should Override fragment method  `onActivityCreated` .. and move  there download Image method

Comment: can you post it as answer please ?@ProblemSlover

Comment: Done! But please include the source of your fragment into your question to make it complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code. that you call downloadMethod inside Fragment `onCreate()` but you should do it inside the `onActivityCreated()` as stated in the source code

> ```
>   onCreated() can be called while the fragment's activity is
>  * still in the process of being created.  As such, you can not rely
>  * on things like the activity's content view hierarchy being initialized
>  * at this point.  If you want to do work once the activity itself is
>  * created, see {@link #onActivityCreated(Bundle)}.
> ```

So here we go

```
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     downloadImage();
}
```

Also You made a mistake in  `onCreateView` :  It should return the view you inflated

E.g it should look like as follows

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.latestjokesfrag, container, false);
        list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.ListView);

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: It didnt work :( .. ill post the full fragment code. i should mention that the downloadimage(); is executing and I am getting output of the println but the adapter is not wroking, if you need more code tell me please i am stuck at it

Comment: Hey wait, Look at the method onCreateView You should return inflated View but you return `inflater.inflate(R.layout.latestjokesfrag, container, false);`  e.g you should return the variable  ' v  '  `final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.latestjokesfrag, container, false);`

Comment: i really apreaciat your support , i need some minutes to check it

Comment: @Moudiz Just have fun  :)